# Groovy reverse map keys

Tags: groovy, dictionary

I would like to get last X entries of a map.

If i would like to get first entries it can be done fairly easy in groovy: `map.take(10)` gets me first 10 entries of a map. But how to get LAST 10 entries? there is no `map.reverse()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `drop` like so:

```
map.drop( map.size() - 10 )
```

To drop all but the last 10 elements

An alternative would be to use the `iterator`, which can be reversed:

```
map.iterator().reverse().take( 10 ).reverse().collect()
```

But it's much messier, and uses more resources

Comment: Works like a charm. I have been reading Map doc for some time and apparently i did not notice.

Comment: There is an argument that `LinkedHashMap` should have a `reverse` method added as it does have the concept of order.  If I get time, I'll try and come up with a patch

Comment: Actually, it looks like it was [discussed a couple of years ago](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3992), but it was decided that  [`reverseEach`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#reverseEach%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) was sufficient.  In this case, it isn't :-(

Comment: It is exacly what i am looking for, i Actually have a LinkedHashMap representing user sessions sorted by date and grouped by sessionID. Therefore i get a map of all user sessions and i needed only 10 last sessions. `map.drop` worked here but embedding it in a lenghty gsp expression in groovy where `map` is a 50 character expression is a little cumbersome. If there was a `reverse()` method it would be more compact.

Comment: @Pma You can reverse the map iterator (see updated answer), but it's not nearly as nice as the parameterised drop...